# Search in belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, associations

sorry for the beginner's question, but I find it hard to understand:

I have assets, in the model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :image
    belongs_to :text
    belongs_to :link
    belongs_to :video
    belongs_to :audio

def self.search(search)
   if search
       where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
     else
       scoped
   end
 end
end
```

each asset type has its own table and `has_many :assets` definition in their model. I'd like to search through the respective asset tables and get items with a specific title (then return them as list of assets). How would it formulate the query? Do I need to use searchlogic?

Comment: I believe this would benefit from changing the relation to [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a chance you describe a bit more what you are trying to achieve? You have an Asset table.  It seems this is where you would put the "title" and return all rows where your LIKE search matches.

And instead of listing multiple belongs_to statements, you may want to make this a polymorphic table instead:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
  :
  :
end
```

And then in each of the other models...

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable
end
```

In this way every asset would have a searchable record in Assets.  Use the [guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) or watch Ryan Bates rails cast on [polymorphic associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).

I look forward to further information.

**## UPDATE ##**

Inside your Asset model, create a class method (e.g. search) like this:

```
def self.search(params) # these are from your search form
  self.where("title like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"
end
```

Params[:search] is the params form your form, and the Asset model retrieves all the records which match.  Your data set will have the assetable_id and assetable_type (which is the other model).  You could display these as links or use this data to retrieve additional info for each model returned, etc.

The key here, as yo will read about and has been explained to me, is to push as much of this type of logic to the model (fat models) and keep your controllers thin.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, each asset has different field, so for 'text' it would be 'body' , 'excerpt' for 'image' - 'url' etc. but all have title field. I want to search through everything. I changed the assoc. to polymorphic, but still not sure about formatting the query

Comment: Let me look into the query part... You are just wanting to be able to search across each table which is associated to the polymorphic table, correct?